# How to use result_of with const overloaded member function

Tags: c++, type-traits

Is there a way to get [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to work with const overloaded member functions? The regular way demonstrated in cppreference doesn't work since the address of the overloaded function can't be resolved.

```
#include <type_traits>

class C {
public:
   auto& f () { return x_; }
   const auto& f() const { return x_; }
private:
   int x_;
};

using FRet = std::result_of_t<decltype(&C::f)(C)>;
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VJ3pteXqsY96LAZg)

Comment: Unless you don't have C++17 available, the short answer is don't use `result_of`. It's a peculiar type trait

Comment: I don't have it fully available unfortunately (Xcode still catching up). I left the c++xx tag free to get the full picture, though.

Comment: So which one do you want, the `const` one or non-`const` one?

Comment: @StoryTeller Man maybe vittorio provided a cleaner answer, your answer was still valid and the approach to that workaround still had value in it. Shouldn't have deleted. :(

Comment: @DeanSeo - Fine. Though let it be known I'm not 100% happy with it given everything

Comment: @StoryTeller agreed with Dean, your approach was interesting to learn from.

Comment: @Danra - It's also not valid C++14, mind you. So that too is to be considered.

Comment: @StoryTeller I also came up with that `std::declval` approach but struggling to deduce the type using `std::result_of` only and your answer just answered my struggling man lol

Comment: @DeanSeo - Then it wasn't a wasted effort :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `result_of` in this situation - you will have to manually disambiguate the overload. You can simply use `decltype` and [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
using FRet = decltype(std::declval<C>().f());
```

If you want to hit the `const` overload, use:

```
using FRet = decltype(std::declval<const C>().f());
```

Comment: Nice. Though I daresay there is no way to do this without disambiguating the overload in some way. Even the choice of argument to `declval` is in and off itself a disambiguation.

Comment: Ah, that's elegant. And though I haven't fully parsed cppreference's example implementation of `invoke_result`, it seems to be doing something similar? (also using declval for the arguments).

Comment: @StoryTeller: yes, that is true. Nevertheless, this can be generalized so that `C` in `std::declval<C>` can be taken as a template parameter. Making `FRet` a template alias would allow its caller to pass the "real" type of `C`.

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't get your point - surely some disambiguation is required, since the compiler must know which function we are talking about. Are you saying there is more disabmiguation going on here then should actually be needed?

Comment: @Danra - Not more than needed. In this you can't hit the const overload any other way. If you had other arguments to the function, so that overload resolution could choose the const overload in other ways, then it would be more interesting, and I wouldn't bemoan the need for being quite so explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually not with `std::result_of`, for all it's peculiarity. The problem is with applying `decltype` to an overload set. That's ambiguous for a good reason. If we were to write `&C::f` in a context where there's an explicit or implciit *target type*, it would be resolved. But naturally there is no target type when we are trying to deduce stuff.

Don't despair *yet*, however. What we can do is simply add a layer of indirection. Lift the overload set into a functor, and apply the type trait to *that*. Applying the recipe will look somewhat like that:

```
class FRetHelper {
    static constexpr auto lifter = [](auto&& a) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::forward<decltype(a)>(a).f();
    };

public:
    using FRet = std::result_of_t<decltype(lifter)(C)>;
};

using FRet = FRetHelper::FRet;
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FFQCAwnlraxbS0zr). Major caveat is that it required [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later (for the constexpr lambda). Which also means, we shouldn't be using `result_of_t`. But, oh well.

Comment: Nice. Don't we need to forward `a` though (to be in more general) ?

Comment: @DeanSeo - We do. Though this half-generalized answer is nowhere near as clean as Vittorio's answer in this case.